# Include MySQL Stored Procedures into a repository?

Tags: mysql, repository, mariadb

Is there a way to include mySQL Stored Procedures to a repository?
...I mean other than having it (manually or automatically) 'duplicated' on a folder included in a repository.

For MariaDB or MySQL. Any of the 'main' repository systems (Git, Mercurial, SVN...)  will be great. Others accepted as well.

*Note*:

Doing some kind of `mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db ...` and dumping the resulting file into a repo folder is not what I'm looking for (I already have that). My question is focused to find out a real integration solution. If any...

Comment: Why only the stored procedures under version control? Why also not the other SQL updates because stored procedures can depend on them..

Comment: What do you mean @Raymond Nijland? Triggers? Functions? ...? The basic answer is 'because I'm not concerned with it at this moment'. But you're right: If I can find a solution that includes so, it will be great.

Comment: no i mean CREATE TABLE statements, CREATE INDEX statements, ALTER statements stuff like that..

Comment: You need to have a main developement MySQL server, and local MySQL server foreach developer... Then you are able with some program to detect changes between the shared MySQL server and local MySQL server and generate a SQL file.. Only problem is you need to manage the change very caryfully within the shared MySQL server and one developer at a time should generate a change SQL and update the shared after.. You can solve that by making a MySQL user account with a connection limit off one i guess.

Comment: @ Raymond Nijland, see my clarification note at the question body.

Answer (score 0):

yes can be done in PHP. Using the following script:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
require "../inc/config.inc.php";

function show_routine(string $type, string $name) {
  global $db;
  $query = "SHOW CREATE $type `$name`";
  $result = $db->query( $query );
  foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo "<h1>$name</h1>";
    if( is_null($row["Create $type"]) ) {
      echo "<p>Not found</p>";
      continue;
    }
    $proc   = $row[$type];
    $source = $row["Create $type"];
    $source = preg_replace( "/(DEFINER=`\w*`@`\w*`)/", "/* $1 */", $source );

    $fh = fopen( "./$type/$name.sql", "w" );
    fwrite( $fh, "DROP $type IF EXISTS `$name`;" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL );
    fwrite( $fh, "DELIMITER $$" . PHP_EOL );
    fwrite( $fh, $source );
    fwrite( $fh, "$$" . PHP_EOL );
    fwrite( $fh, "DELIMITER ;" . PHP_EOL );
    fclose( $fh );
  }
}


foreach( $db->query("show procedure status where db = '<your-db>'") as $row ) {
  $name = $row["Name"];
  show_routine("Procedure", $name);
}


foreach( $db->query("show function status where db = '<your-db>'") as $row ) {
  $name = $row["Name"];
  show_routine("Function", $name);
}
```

make sure the db user has the correct rights and the sp were created with this.  Files are created per function/sp in the proper directory.